# Ruby split keep the delimiter before the string

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following string :

```
a = '% abc \n %% abcd \n %% efgh\n '
```

I would like the ouput to be

```
['% abc \n', '%% abcd \n', '%% efgh \n']
```

If I have

```
b = '%% abc \n %% efg \n %% ijk \n]
```

I would like the output to be

```
['%% abc \n', '%% efg \n', '%% ijk \n']
```

I use `b.split('%%').collect!{|v| '%%' + v }` and it works fine for case 2.

but it doesn't work for case 1.

I saw some post of using 'scan' or 'split' to keep the delimiter if its after the string

```
For example : 'a; b; c' becomes ['a;', 'b;' ,'c']

But I want the opposite ['a', ';b', ';c']
```

There need not be space between \n and %% since \n depicts a new line.

A solution i made was

```
sel = '% asd \n %% asf sdaf \n %% adsasd asdf asd asf ';
delimiter = '%%';
indexOfPercent = test_string.index("%%")

if(indexOfPercent == 0)
    result = (test_string || '').split(delimiter).reject(&:empty?).collect! {|v| delimiter + v}
else
    result =  (test_string.slice(test_string.index("%%")..-1) || '').split(delimiter).reject(&:empty?).collect! {|v| delimiter + v}
    result.unshift(sel[0.. indexOfPercent-1])
end
```

Comment: is `\n` really a newline character?

Comment: Yes \n is new line character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=\\n)\s*(?=%%)
```

You can split on the `space` using `lookarounds`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/7

Comment: There need not be a space between \n and %% since \n depicts a new line

Comment: Interesting. Let me give that a try.

Comment: The above solution is not working when instead of \n the string has actual Enter..

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way

```
def splitter(s)
  #reject(&:empty) added to handle trailing space in a
  s.lines.map{|n| n.lstrip.chomp(' ')}.reject(&:empty?)
end 

#double quotes used to keep ruby from changing 
# \n to \\n
a = "% abc \n %% abcd \n %% efgh\n "
b = "b = '%% abc \n %% efg \n %% ijk \n"

splitter(a)
#=> ["% abc \n", "%% abcd \n", "%% efgh\n"]
splitter(b)
#=> ["%% abc \n", "%% efg \n", "%% ijk \n"]
```

`String#lines` will partition the string right after the newline character by default. (This will return an `Array`. Then we call `Array#map` and pass in each matching string. This string then calls `lstrip` to remove the leading space and `chomp(' ')` to remove the trailing space without removing the `\n`. Then we `reject` any empty strings as would be the case in variable `a` because of the trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
a.split(/\\n\s?/).collect{|e| "#{e}\\n"}

a.split(/\\n\s?/)
# ["% abc ", "%% abcd ", "%% efgh"]
.collect{|e| "#{e}\\n"}
# will append \n
# ["% abc \\n", "%% abcd \\n", "%% efgh\\n"]
```